# Opening message inbox programmatically in iphone

Tags: iphone, sms

Can I open (Sms) message inbox and perform actions on it (like reading,deleting etc) programatically in iphone?

Answer (score 2):

You can but only on a jailbroken device. Else you don't have any access to the SMS database. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access anything out of your application's sandbox unless you are using methods provided to you by Apple (like UIImagePicker). Your application will not be allowed on the app store even if you somehow manage to do so.

If you are not worried about getting your app on the app store, then you can try jailbreaking the device and accessing the SMS database